# How can I separete environments (dev, prod, staging) in AWS using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using workspaces to separate environments in AWS like that:

```
terraform init
terraform workspace new dev
terraform workspace select dev
terraform validate --var-file $(terraform workspace show).tfvars
terraform apply --var-file $(terraform workspace show).tfvars
```

The command `$(terraform workspace show).tfvars` is used to select as `--var-file` the file with the same name as the workspace, in this case, `dev.tfvars` will be used.

There are a better option?

Comment: workspaces are fine. Why would you want to change it?

Answer (score 1):

In my team, we decided to follow the per-folder environment pattern, similar to what is recommended by Terragrunt
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example